# Jenkins : Conditional build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have to build multiple jobs in jenkin which are interdependant.
the process which I want to do is as follows -
1.  Poll SVN for A

```
If there is any change  
   build test-suit A 
   execute test-suit A
else 
   do nothing,continue to next step
```

2. Poll SVN for B

   If there is any change
     build test-suit B 
     execute test-suit B

   else 
     do nothing,continue to next step
3. Poll SVN for C

I have used Conditional build step and it works as

1. Poll SVN for A

   If there is any change
      build test-suit A 
      execute test-suit A

   else

   ```
    stop
   ```

can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

What if there are changes in B? Do you not want to build it?

Typically you set up Jenkins jobs either as a whole (ie a single job that builds A, then B then C in turn) or you set up independent jobs that may build child dependencies (ie A will always build B, and B will always build C).